# How to find matching has_and_belongs_to_many associations between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, associations

Lets say I have two models: Debater and Team.

Team has_and_belongs_to_many Debaters and vice-versa.

I want to be able to query from the Team class to find teams that habtm to two **specified** debaters.

I would also like to be able to query from the Debater class to find whether the debater has a team with a specified debater.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `@team.debaters` you get all debaters for that team. The other way around you can get all teams for a debater with `@debater.teams`. Now if you want to get all the teams in which two debaters are present you could do `Team.where("debater_id == #{id1} OR debater_id == #{id2}")`.

For you last point (uery from the Debater class to find whether the debater has a team with a specified debater) you could try the following `@debater.teams.where(:debater_id => DEBATER_ID)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: debater_id is not an attribute of Team because it has a habtm association with Debater. I don't know enough about sqlite but I would think the query has to do the following:

Search debaters_teams where team_ids are equal AND where one record has debater_id = debater_id_1 and where the other record has debater_id debater_id_2